# Override Cordova plugin dependency

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have two Cordova plugins each requiring different Gradle library versions. Is there a way to force both plugins to use the latest version?

Or will I have to create clones of the plugin source and modify the dependency manually in the plugin.xml file?

Comment: Depends what libraries they are and how they are required (Gradle vs bundled jar/aar)

Comment: Sorry, I meant Gradle dependencies

Comment: Which libraries?

Answer (score 0):

This might solve it for you. It did for me, but admittedly my scenario was not quite the same.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release